# Integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(xy)^k}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^p}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Determine the Integral:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(xy)^k}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^p} \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y$$
The answer seems to be $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$$
that has no dependence on $p$, although I am not sure as I donot have the answer and this was verified using desmos for smaller values.

The integral is simplified to
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}y^k(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x)^k}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^p} \mathrm{d} x) \mathrm{d} y$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}y^k(\int_{0}^{1}\ x^k\left(1+(\frac{y}{x})^p  \right)^{-1} \mathrm{d} x) \mathrm{d} y$$

Now using $(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }(-1)^rx^r$
$$(1+(\frac{y}{x})^p)^{-1} = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty }(-1)^r(\frac{y}{x})^{pr}$$
$$=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }(-1)^ry^{pr}x^{-pr}$$
The inner integral can then be evaluated as:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ x^k\left(1+(\frac{y}{x})^p  \right)^{-1} \mathrm{d} x = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty }(-1)^ry^{pr}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-pr} \mathrm{d} x$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-pr} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{k-pr+1}, r\neq \frac{k+1}{p}
$$
I am not sure what to do when $r=\frac{k+1}{p}$ as we will be integrating $\frac{1}{x}$ from $0$ to $1$ which comes out to be undefined.
Leaving that term out:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ x^k\left(1+(\frac{y}{x})^p  \right)^{-1} \mathrm{d} x =\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^ry^{pr}}{k-pr+1}$$

Now
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(xy)^k}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^p} \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^r}{k-pr+1}\int_{0}^{1}y^{k+pr} \mathrm dy$$

The integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}y^{k+pr} \mathrm{d} y = \frac{1}{k+pr+1}, r\neq -(\frac{k+1}{p})$$
Again the same restrictions on $r$ but $r$ cannot be negative so this won't happen.
Finally the original integral becomes:
$$I=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^r}{(k-pr+1)(k+pr+1)}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2(k+1)}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty } (\frac{(-1)^{r}}{k-pr+1}+\frac{(-1)^{r}}{k+pr+1})$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2(k+1)}(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty } (\frac{(-1)^{r}}{k-pr+1})+\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }(\frac{(-1)^{r}}{k+pr+1}))$$

I don't know how to evaluate those sums, individually putting them into wolfram gives an answer with Hurwitz Lerch Transcendent. Although together they seem to give:
$$\frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{\pi}{2p}(\tan(\frac{\pi k}{2p}+\frac{\pi}{2p})+\cot(\frac{\pi k}{2p}+\frac{\pi}{2p}))$$
Hence,
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} + \frac{\pi}{4p(k+1)}(\tan(\frac{\pi k}{2p}+\frac{\pi}{2p})+\cot(\frac{\pi k}{2p}+\frac{\pi}{2p}))$$
Which is close to the answer guessed at the beginning (except the trigonometric terms ofcourse). Though it seems I have made a mistake somewhere as the trig terms are affecting the answer making it wrong.
Well this was my way of attempt, I am guessing there must be a better way than using the binomial to expand.

Comment: You can't use that formula for $(1+x)^{-1}$ if $x>1$ or, in terms of the problem's integration variables, $y>x$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for pointing that out, I seem to have used the wrong expansion.

Comment: @BlackEmperor Bro double integral in jee syllabus?!!!

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman No, I just do recreational Maths around Integrals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The domain is symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$. Thus, if we in
\begin{equation*}
  I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(xy)^k}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^{p}}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^p(xy)^k}{x^p+y^p}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\tag{1}
 \end{equation*}
change $x$ to $y$ and $y$ to $x$ we  get
\begin{equation*}
  I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{y^p(xy)^k}{x^p+y^p}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y.\tag{2}
 \end{equation*}
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields
\begin{equation*}
 2I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(x^p+y^p)(xy)^k}{x^p+y^p}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y  =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(xy)^k\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y =\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}.
\end{equation*}
Consequently
\begin{equation*}
 I=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I seem to have grasped the solution, but I don't understand the first line, could you elaborate that once. What conditions must be met so as to exchange x and y?

Comment: @BlackEmperor: No conditions required (considering $I$
 as a *double* integral - not as an *iterated* one). We just *rename* the variables, one into another and vice versa.

Comment: @Black Emperor With the variable substitution
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
 x &=\quad v\\
 y&=u
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
the domain $0\le x\le 1,\, 0\le y \le 1$ corresponds to the domain  $0\le u \le 1,\, 0\le v \le 1 $. For the Jacobian we get $\dfrac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}=-1. $ Thus
\begin{equation*}
 I= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{v^p(vu)^k}{v^p+u^p}\cdot|-1|\,\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v.
\end{equation*}